# Poster frame of embedded YouTube video larger than video

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I am embedding a YouTube video into an HTML page. I want the video to appear as large as possible in the browser window. Here is the CSS that I am using for the embedded iframe:

```
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

When the video is playing, it fits the window nicely, keeping its aspect ratio and showing empty space either above-and-below or left-and-right, as I would expect.

However, the initial poster image fills the window completely. I would like it to adjust its height and width so that it has the same dimensions and position as the video.

I thought I could access the elements in the video iframe, to discover the dimensions of the video. However, when I use `document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document`, I get an error warning that accessing a cross-origin frame is blocked.

How can I detect the aspect ratio of the video, so that I can set the dimensions of the iframe correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. However, it means providing hard-coded values for the dimensions of the video.

On YouTube, I right-click to bring up the "Stats for Nerds" and note the `Current / Optimal Res` (for example: 1280x720@30). In the HTML, I provide the relevant information as `--width` and `--height` CSS variables:

HTML:

```
<iframe style="
          --width:1280;
          --height:720;
        "
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fUyU3lKzoio"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

In the CSS, I set the `width` and `height` to the full size of the window (using `vw` and `vh` units, which return the full available size on smartphones and tablets). I also cap the `max-height` and `max-width`, to ensure that the aspect ratio of the video is respected:

CSS:

```
iframe {
  width:  100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: calc(100vw / var(--width) * var(--height));
  max-width:  calc(100vh * var(--width) / var(--height));
}
```